# TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances when trying to use fractions

Tags: python, calculus, python-fractions

So im trying to write a code that will solve general solutions in calculus and one of my values is a fraction with `f1 = fractions.Fraction(2.0, period)` but if I use **12.5** as the period it comes back with an error.
Code:

```
from cmath import sin
import math
import re
import operator
import fractions
from decimal import Decimal

amplitude = input("What is the A value?: ")
period = input("What is the P value?: ")
ogperiod = float(period)
period = float(period)


f1 = fractions.Fraction(2.0, period)
print(f1)
```

But all I get is **TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances**
full error code:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [84], in <cell line: 27>()
     23 ogperiod = float(period)
     24 period = float(period)
---> 27 f1 = fractions.Fraction(2.0, period)
     28 print(f1)
     31 bpi = 2 * math.pi

File /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/fractions.py:152, in Fraction.__new__(cls, numerator, denominator, _normalize)
    147     numerator, denominator = (
    148         numerator.numerator * denominator.denominator,
    149         denominator.numerator * numerator.denominator
    150         )
    151 else:
--> 152     raise TypeError("both arguments should be "
    153                     "Rational instances")
    155 if denominator == 0:
    156     raise ZeroDivisionError('Fraction(%s, 0)' % numerator)

TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that one problem is to assign a `float` to `period`. `Fraction` class has a constructor that accepts two values (the numerator and the denominator) of a `Rational` class (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction)). Since *Python* version 3.2, there is the possibility of initialize a `Fraction` from a `float` but only using one parameter.

So, if you want to keep the 2 values (2.0 and `period`), you have to change 2.0 to 2 and use `period` as `int` (loosing precision). So, your code will be:

```
f1 = fractions.Fraction(2, int(period))
```

---

**EDIT**:

If you want to keep the precision of `period`, it's better to convert it to a fraction and do the fractional division to initialize `f1`. That is:

```
period = fractions.Fraction(period)
f1 = fractions.Fraction(2 * period.denominator, period.nominator)
```

Comment: So when i use `f1 = fractions.Fraction(2 / period)` it comes back with **2263756080649101/4503599627370496** when i want it to come back with **0.16**

Comment: Yes, you are right so, in that case, do the fractional division. I've just edited the answer with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback tells you exactly what the problem is: both the numerator and denominator of the `Fraction` instance need to be rational numbers - that is, a number that is expressed as the ratio of two integers. Floats are not rational in and of themselves, due to the way they are implemented in hardware. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for details.

Basically, the numerator and denominator of a [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) instance need to be either `int`s or `Fraction`s themselves.